# How do I create this route and use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

Currently I am using the default route but I need a route that works like this:

```
localhost/Admin/Users/Index
localhost/Admin/Users/Add
localhost/Admin/Users/Delete
```

Where index add and delete are views with controllers in the AdminController.cs

The current structure everywhere else is fine, as it doesn't require multiple subdirectories.

Currently I have the the file I need to start with in:

```
{Project}/Views/Admin/Users/Index.cshtml
```

How would I create this route and how do I apply it to the controller?

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: How about using `route attributes` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: Okay, I am using `[Route("/Users/{id?}")]` on my Users() action in the Admin Controller. It works however I need to explicitly state the view to which I am referring: `return View("Users/Index", model);`

I was trying to avoid having to explicitly state the view.

Comment: How about `[Route("/Admin/Users/Index/{id?}")]`?

Comment: I believe attrib routes cannot begin with a slash.

Comment: `[Route("Admin/Users/{id?}")]` and  `[Route("Admin/Users/Edit/{id?}")]` works.
As for my directory structure, because it isn't standard, it is unavoidable. 
Mind making your solution the answer so I can mark it as the answer for future visitors? :)

Comment: Sorry, I just add the prefix to the route provided on your comment(that also start with an slash)...but you get the idea!

Comment: Ok @Bitz, I am going to post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily resolved using `Route attributes`, like:

```
[Route("Admin/Users/Edit/{id?}")]
public ActionResult TestView(string id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        return View(“OneUser”, GetUser(id));
    }
    return View(“AlUsers”, GetUsers());
}
```

#### MSDN: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 0):

You can register another route specifying the route path and the controller in `RegisterRoutes`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "{controller}/Users/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { controller = "Admin" }
);
```

To handle your directory structure you need to extend the default view engine to add the new view paths:

```
public class ExtendedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public ExtendedRazorViewEngine()
    {
        List<string> existingPaths = new List<string>(ViewLocationFormats);
        existingPaths.Add("~/Views/Admin/Users/{0}.cshtml");

        ViewLocationFormats = existingPaths.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And register the engine in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

    ExtendedRazorViewEngine engine = new ExtendedRazorViewEngine();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(engine);

    ...
}
```